# ¿Cómo crear una matriz 3d en python, en la cual, cada una de las matrices que la compone, pueden llegar a tener diferentes números de filas?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

soy nuevo programando y estoy aprendiendo en python. Necesito crear una matriz 3d para guardar las coordenadas X,Y de los puntos que componen diferentes polígonos. La idea es que cada matriz represente un polígono y en esta se guarden las coordenadas que lo componen. El problema es que puedo tener polígonos de toda clase, como triángulos (compuesto por 3 puntos), cuadrados (4 puntos), hexágonos (6 puntos), etc. Posteriormente debo debo revisar que estos polígonos no se salgan de un área (deben estar cerca los unos de los otros) pero obtengo un error que dice "IndexError: too many indices for array" y no entiendo por qué, ya que si todos los polígonos tienen la misma cantidad de puntos, el código funciona perfectamente.

Adjunto el código.

```
import numpy as np
xi=0
yi=0
LX=10
LY=10
poly=np.array([[(1,1),(3,1),(3,3),(1,3)],[(4,1),(8,1),(8,3),(4,3)],[(5,5),(7,5),(6,6)]])
"""Verificar que los poligonos no se salgan del muro"""
for i in range(len(poly)):
    for j in range(len(poly[i])):
        if poly[i,j,0]<xi or poly[i,j,0]>LX or poly[i,j,1]<yi or poly[i,j,1]>LY:
            print "Poligono fuera del muro"




IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Comment: Dime si te funciona mi respuesta @Juan José

Answer (score 0):

Aquí **lo que estás creando no es un matriz 3D, son 3 vectores**, que esto es 1D, que es distinto.

Como tienes 3 vectores, no pudes indexar de la forma que lo estás haciendo `poly[i,j,0]` ya que esta forma es para matrices 3D (tensores). Por ello te da el error `IndexError: too many indices for array` que viene a decir, que estás realizando una indexación para una tensor 3D cuando tienes un vector. **Es decir que estás realizando demasiadas indexaciones, para los datos que tienes-**

### Hacemos la indexación correcta

```
import numpy as np
xi=0
yi=0
LX=10
LY=10
poly=np.array([[(1,1),(3,1),(3,3),(1,3)],[(4,1),(8,1),(8,3),(4,3)],[(5,5),(7,5),(6,6)]])
"""Verificar que los poligonos no se salgan del muro"""
for i in range(len(poly)):
    for j in range(len(poly[i])):
        print(poly[i][j][0])
        #Aquí cambiamos la forma de indexar
        if poly[i][j][0]<xi or poly[i][j][0] > LX or poly[i][j][1]<yi or poly[i][j][1]>LY:
            print "Poligono fuera del muro"
```